# AJAX call from on-click fails

Tags: node.js, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, express, onclick

I have a bizarre error where ajax call in a on('click') listener executed from an external trigger('click') call will fail, but execute correctly if the on('click') listener is called via a regular user mouse-click.

HTML:

```
....
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto navbar-right">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown active">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="nbd" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Graphs<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item ycai" id="d1" href="#" data-type="1">Graph 1</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item ycai" id="d2" href="#" data-type="2">Graph 2</a>
        </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 navbar-right">
    <div id="nbsa"></div>
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="nbpc" placeholder="Postal Code" style="width:140px" aria-label="Postal Code" type="search">
    <select class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="nbs">
      <option value="1" selected="true">Average-case</option>
      <option value="2">High-case</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
  var dataV = {
    gtype:2,
    nbpc: null,
    nbs:  null
  };

  $('#nbpc').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      dataV.nbpc = $(this).val();
      switch(dataV.gtype) {
        case 1:
          $('#d1').trigger('click');
          break;
        case 2:
          $('#d2').trigger('click');
          break;
      }
    }
  });

  $('#nbtop').on('click', '.ycai', function(e) {
    console.log('In Click...',$(this).attr('data-type'));
    e.preventDefault();
    var i=0, rval;
    if (!$(this).hasClass("dislink")) {
      $(this).addClass("dislink");
      dataV.nbpc = $('#nbpc').val();
      dataV.nbs = $('#nbs').val();
      dataV.gtype = +$(this).attr('data-type');
      console.log(dataV);
      if (dataV.gtype<8 && dataV.nbpc == "") {
        alert('Postal Code Cannot Be Blank...');
        $('.dislink').removeClass('dislink');
        $('#nbpc').focus();
        return;
      }

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/climG',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: dataV
      }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(error);
        alert('Error on Graph');
      }).done(function(res) {
        ...
      });
```

Scenario #1: If I add the postal-code in (#nbpc) first (without hitting Enter) and then select a graph (say Graph 2), the ajax call goes thru and executes perfectly.

Scenario #2: If I add the postal-code in (#nbpc) and then hit Enter, which defaults to Graph 2 and then executes the $('#d2').trigger('click'); via the $('#nbpc') keyup listener, then the ajax call will fail with no error message.

What is interesting are the node.js console lines.

In Scenario #1, the console log lines are perfect:

```
Console Log Line 1
... 
Console Log Line N
POST /climG 200 378.344ms - 1872
```

In Scenario #2 (error), the console log lines are very strange:

```
GET /? 304 192.332 ms - -
POST /climG - - ms - -
Console Log Line 1
... 
Console Log Line N
```

So in Scenario #2, an extra GET /? is generated for some unknown-to-me reason, and the /climG call quickly returns a failure, yet the actual /climG server-side function continues to execute (evidenced by the console log lines after the POST message). I have no clue what's happening. Thx.

Comment: Thanks, but this did not work.

Comment: the `form` element will default to `GET` as its action - if you are not using the form to submit your data, you can safely remove this tag.  It's likely being triggered by pressing the `enter` key - before you even get a chance to execute the JS...

Comment: Worked. Thx. Seems strange that e.preventDefaults didn't do what it's supposed to do. Anyway...

Comment: ok, I turned the comment into an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `form` element will default to `GET` as its action - if you are not using the form to submit your data, you can safely remove this tag.

It's likely being triggered by pressing the <kbd>enter</kbd> key - before you even get a chance to execute the JS.

In other words, change

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 navbar-right">
    <div id="nbsa"></div>
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="nbpc" placeholder="Postal Code" style="width:140px" aria-label="Postal Code" type="search">
    <select class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="nbs">
      <option value="1" selected="true">Average-case</option>
      <option value="2">High-case</option>
    </select>
  </form>
```

to

```
<div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 navbar-right">
    <div id="nbsa"></div>
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="nbpc" placeholder="Postal Code" style="width:140px" aria-label="Postal Code" type="search">
    <select class="form-control mr-sm-2" id="nbs">
      <option value="1" selected="true">Average-case</option>
      <option value="2">High-case</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```